# Eurail Two country Pass - Is it valid for travel within city transport?

Tags: europe, france, switzerland, eurail

I want to know whether the "Eurail Two Country Pass" would allow to travel within the city using any internal trains?

For an example if I buy a Two Country Eurail Pass for France - Switzerland, would I be able to Travel 'within' Paris and Zurich separately?

If not, what is the most economical way to visit Eiffel tower, Louvre Museum, Disneyland etc. (Within the city Paris)?

Answer (score 4):

Taking France as an example the "Eurail Two Country Pass" is valid for SNCF and Irish Ferries travel. Neither of which operates the mass transit systems in Paris. For travel within Paris you might want a [carnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnet_(ticket)) for the Métro or a [pass](http://parisbytrain.com/paris-train-metro-week-pass-navigo-decouverte/). Which is best value for you is not a Travel matter.

Comment: SNCF does operate some of the mass transit in Paris. Not the line to Disneyland though, and even for the lines that SNCF does operate, it seems that Eurail is not valid though I can't find reliable information.

Answer (score 2):

Disneyland is not **in** Paris, it is near Paris and you might be able to find trains there on your two countries rail pass.

The other two locations within Paris are rather close together, you can easily walk from one to the other. It is also possible to go by bus, one metro ticket, and with a bit more effort underground in the Metro, also just one metro ticket but a bit more walking if I remember right.

I have checked internet again for the use of Railpasses in the RER trains and only found old mentions of it being possible on some trains but not all. Maybe by now it is not allowed anymore, but do ask if you need to take an RER train and happen to have that pass.

Comment: While there are a handful of trains that are covered by Eurail and go through Marne-la-Vallée-Chessy-Disneyland, those trains are high-speed trains connecting the eastern Paris suburbs with other cities in France, they don't go to Paris. If Eurail passes are usable on some RER trains (which is doubtful), it's only on the ones run by SNCF, which does not include the line to Disneyland.

Answer (score 2):

I've found conflicting information regarding the validity of Eurail in Paris. [Eurail.com's list of airport-station links](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/travel-resources/airport-train-station-connections) lists the connections between Paris and the CDG (Roissy) and Orly airport, both operated by SNCF, as not covered. However, [Eurail.com's list of participating companies](http://www.eurail.com/europe-by-train/trains/participating-railway-companies) mentions “SNCF” without restrictions. Some other sources, e.g. [Rail Europe](https://www.raileurope.com/rail-tickets-passes/france-pass/index.html) and [EurailTickets.com](http://www.eurailtickets.com/pass.php?name=francenswitzerland), claim that those specific connections are covered, which suggests that Paris suburban trains operated by SNCF are covered. Participants on [this forum thread](http://fodoronline.com/community/europe/how-to-use-a-transilien-train-from-paris-in-ile-de-france.cfm) give conflicting information and suggest that the rules may have changed at some point.

In any case, the RER line to Disneyland is operated by RATP, not by SNCF, and no RATP line is covered by Eurail. Of the main suburban tourist destinations, SNCF operates RER C including the branch to the Versailles palace, and the part of RER B between Roissy airport and Gare du Nord. RER A to Disneyland and the metro in Paris are not operated by SNCF.

In any case, using an Eurail pass for local transport would only make sense if you also make a long-distance trip the same day, otherwise it would make local transportation extremely expensive. For Paris, the general advice is to buy either a [day ticket (Mobilis)](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/v_154905/mobilis-une-journee/) if you travel a lot, or a booklet of 10 tickets for local transport. Most tourist attractions are within the city limits, where an ordinary ticket-t suffices. Disneyland and Versailles are outside the city limits, in zone 4 and 5 respectively. Note that most tourist information in English mentions the [Paris Visite](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61634/paris-visite/) pass, but that's mostly a tourist trap; the Mobilis pass or individual tickets usually comes out significantly cheaper cheaper (e.g. €15.20 for a return between the city center and Disneyland, €17.30 for a day pass that covers this trip, €24.50 for a 1-day Paris Visite pass that covers this trip).

For Zurich, [Eurail](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/travel-resources/airport-train-station-connections) states that the pass is valid on the train link from the airport to the city, and several secondary sources claim that it's valid on all S-Bahn trains. Generally, in Germany and Switzerland, it seems that all S-Bahn trains are covered by the Eurail pass.

Answer (score 0):

be aware that transilien (the parisian part of SNCF) is usually not include in any pass. 
so the best is to take ticket or take the mobilis pqss